# Strange results with MongoDB group aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two different documents I would like to group with a matching field (`idOrdem` in this case). Both has a `timestamp` filed and only one has a `timeElapsed` field. I need all of this information to be returned in the aggregation, but the result I'm getting doesn't seem to be correct. I get `null` results for the `timeElapsed` field where there is definetly a document with this field.

What is wrong with my statement?

```
db.Logging.aggregate( [
 { $match : { $or : [ { "action":"resetDslVerify"}, { "action":"assia/reset/RequestQueryOs" } ] } },
 { $group : {
    _id : "$idOrdem",
    timestamp1: { $first: '$timestamp' },
    timestamp2: { $last: '$timestamp' },
    timeElapsed: { $first: '$timeElapsed' }
    }
 },
 { $sort: { timestamp: -1}  } ]
);
```

The unexpected result:

```
{ "_id" : "159251", "timestamp1" : 1483456382058, "timestamp2" : 1483456382058, "timeElapsed" : 1091 }
{ "_id" : "134601", "timestamp1" : 1482949316671, "timestamp2" : 1482949349410, "timeElapsed" : 821 }
{ "_id" : "168801", "timestamp1" : 1483560599899, "timestamp2" : 1483560564505, "timeElapsed" : null }
{ "_id" : "158901", "timestamp1" : 1483452698756, "timestamp2" : 1483452673424, "timeElapsed" : null }
{ "_id" : "135001", "timestamp1" : 1482949653229, "timestamp2" : 1482949711541, "timeElapsed" : 838 }
```

An example of documents with matching `idOrdem` with all the information I need:

```
s-1:PRIMARY> db.Logging.find( { $or : [ { "action":"resetDslVerify"}, { "action":"assia/reset/RequestQueryOs" } ], "idOrdem":"135001" } );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("586404155b88db1209c3f998"), "success" : true, "action" : "assia/reset/RequestQueryOs", "timestamp" : 1482949653229, "httpCode" : 200, "timeElapsed" : 838, "idOrdem" : "135001", "creator" : "TecnicoVirtual" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5864044f5b88db1209c3f99b"), "success" : true, "action" : "resetDslVerify", "timestamp" : 1482949711541, "terminal" : "2134599099", "httpCode" : 200, "idOrdem" : "135001", "idOrdem" : "135001", "result" : "OK", "timestamp" : 1482949711541, "isResetDslSuccess" : true, "creator" : "TecnicoVirtual" }
```

Comment: Can you show your expected results as well?

Comment: The data in the "unexpected result" are not corresponding to the ones in the "matching documents" below. Can you, e.g., provide the data that are producing: 


{ "_id" : "158901", "timestamp1" : 1483452698756, "timestamp2" : 1483452673424, "timeElapsed" : null }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** and **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** accumulators return a value from the first/last document for each group respectively. Order is only defined if the documents are in a defined order but in your case you are ordering
them `AFTER` grouping them in arbitrary order, which renders the accumulators useless as they only return the documents in that undefined order, hence getting the strange results.

To debug the pipeline, run it cumulatively adding each step and inspect the resulting documents at each step. So for example, you could start with just the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline and verify if the results at that stage only are the expected:

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "action": { 
                "$in": [
                    "resetDslVerify",
                    "assia/reset/RequestQueryOs"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Observe the resulting documents at this stage which should be documents that match the given criteria (shortened to use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in)** operator in your case) and arbitrary ordered.

Add the next pipeline step:

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "action": { 
                "$in": [
                    "resetDslVerify",
                    "assia/reset/RequestQueryOs"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$idOrdem",
            "timestamp1": { "$first": "$timestamp" }
            "timestamp2": { "$last": "$timestamp" }
            "timeElapsed": { "$first": "$timeElapsed" }
        }
    }
])
```

Now this is where things get interesting, the documents from the resulting pipeline are in arbitrary order because they entered the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** phase in that order. Even placing a final **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline step will not remove the fly in the celebration ointment: it won't alter the order of the original documents, just the order of the `GROUP`.

---

The solution is to filter out the nulls in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** step,  place the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator before the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, as well as adding the other sort field which will be your group by key and the `timeElapsed` attribute:

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "action": { 
                "$in": [
                    "resetDslVerify",
                    "assia/reset/RequestQueryOs"
                ]
            },
            "timestamp": { "$ne": null },
            "timeElapsed": { "$ne": null }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "idOrdem": 1, "timestamp": -1, "timeElapsed": -1 } }
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$idOrdem",
            "timestamp1": { "$first": "$timestamp" }
            "timestamp2": { "$last": "$timestamp" }
            "timeElapsed": { "$first": "$timeElapsed" }
        }
    }
])
```

A better approach which doesn't use the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline would be to use the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** and **[`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#grp._S_min)** operators:

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "action": { 
                "$in": [
                    "resetDslVerify",
                    "assia/reset/RequestQueryOs"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$idOrdem",
            "timestamp1": { "$max": "$timestamp" }
            "timestamp2": { "$min": "$timestamp" }
            "timeElapsed": { "$max": "$timeElapsed" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: The first approach still gave me nulls. The second one, with max/min was spot on. Thanks. :)

Comment: No worries :) I have updated the answer so that you can filter the nulls.

Answer (score 1):

$first will take the value for the first document even if the field doesn't exist fr this doc. You can fix this issue like this:

```
db.Logging.aggregate([
   {
      $match:{
         $or:[
            {
               "action":"resetDslVerify"
            },
            {
               "action":"assia/reset/RequestQueryOs"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:"$idOrdem",
         timestamp1:{
            $first:'$timestamp'
         },
         timestamp2:{
            $last:'$timestamp'
         },
         timeElapsed:{
            $push:"$timeElapsed"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project:{
         _id:1,
         timestamp1:1,
         timestamp2:1,
         timeElapsed:{
            $arrayElemAt:[
               "$timeElapsed",
               0
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $sort:{
         timestamp:-1
      }
   }
]);
```

output: (for the data you provided)

```
{ "_id" : "135901", "timestamp1" : 1482950884849, "timestamp2" : 1482950907877, "timeElapsed" : 801 }
```

Comment: exception: invalid operator '$arrayElemAt'

Comment: @ChristianDechery $arrayElemAt was introduced in mongoDB 3.2, I guess you are using an older version